# Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb error

Tags: curl, certificate, centos7, libcurl, nss

I use `Centos 7` and curl version is `curl 7.29.0` and i want `send email` with this structure:

`curl --url "smtps://mail.domain.com:587" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "username@domain.com" --mail-rcpt "account@gmail.com" --upload-file /root/mail.txt --user "user@domain.com:password" -vvv`

```
curl --url "smtps://mail.domain.com:587" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "username@domain.com" --mail-rcpt "account@gmail.com" --upload-file /root/mail.txt --user "user@domain.com:password" -vvv 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to mail.domain.com port 587 (#0)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* Connected to mail.domain.com (1.2.3.4) port 587 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:24 --:--:--     0^C
```

But at this stage you get stuck. I searched a lot but did not find any. The nss package is also an update.

```
[root@cache2 ~]# rpm -aq | grep nss
nss-softokn-freebl-3.53.1-6.el7_9.x86_64
nss-tools-3.53.1-3.el7_9.x86_64
nss-softokn-3.53.1-6.el7_9.x86_64
nss-pem-1.0.3-7.el7.x86_64
nss-sysinit-3.53.1-3.el7_9.x86_64
nss-util-3.53.1-1.el7_9.x86_64
openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
nss-3.53.1-3.el7_9.x86_64
```

```
[root@cache2 ~]# ll  /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 49 Jun 15 10:20 /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
[root@cache2 ~]#
```

How can I solve this problem?